# Get Results from two functions and display it on one view

Tags: laravel, eloquent, laravel-blade

I have a db user records which has columns: user_id and supervisor_id. For a logged user, he/she can be a user and also can be a supervisor to others.
I want to display two tables where table 1 will display all the user records which have user_id for the logged user and table 2 to display all the user_records which have supervisor_id of the logged user.

This is my code on the controller.

```
public function user_record()
    {
        $user_id = Auth::user()->id;

        $show_leave= DB::table('user_record')->where('user_id','=',$user_id)->get();

    }
    public function show_user_record(Request $request)
    {
        $user_id = Auth::user()->id;

        $show_user_record= DB::table('user_record')->where('supervisor','=',$user_id )->get();

        $user_record=$this->user_record();

        return view('/user_records', compact('show_user_record','user_record'));
    }
```

user_records blade file:

```
<table>
<tr>
<th>#</th>
<th>Full Name</th>
<th>Status</th>
<th>Remarks</th>
</tr>
@foreach($show_user_record as $data)
<tr>
<td>{{$data->id}}</td>
<td>{{$data->full_name}}</td>
<td>{{$data->status}}</td>
<td>{{$data->remarks}}</td>
</tr>
@endforeach
</table>

<table>
<tr>
<th>#</th>
<th>Full Name</th>
<th>Status</th>
<th>Remarks</th>
</tr>
@foreach($user_record as $user_data)
<tr>
<td>{{$user_data->id}}</td>
<td>{{$user_data->full_name}}</td>
<td>{{$user_data->status}}</td>
<td>{{$user_data->remarks}}</td>
</tr>
@endforeach
</table>
```

Error:
foreach() argument must be of type array|object, null given
@foreach($user_record as $user_data)

Answer (score 0):

you did not return anything in the **user_record()** function so it is null , and the foreach() accept a sort of collection.

th fix is to use a return in the method

```
public function user_record()
    {
        $user_id = Auth::user()->id;

        $show_leave= DB::table('user_record')->where('user_id','=',$user_id)->get();
        return $show_leave;
    }
```

other remarks for better coding would be to use the **ORM** instead of the query builder if possible, also i don't see why two methods , i think its better to make just one
finally make sure your code is nullsafe by testing the variable before going into the foreach because this will fail if there are no records

Comment: This solved the issue. I was getting the results but not displaying it properly.